# Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float

Tags: php, parsing, floating-point

I have a list of prices with a comma for a decimal point and a dot as the thousand separator.

Some examples:

**12,30

116,10

1.563,14**

These come in this format from a third party. I want to convert them to floats and add them together.

What is the best way to do this? **number_format** doesn't seem to work with this format, and **str_replace** seems like overkill, as I have to do it more that once on each number.

Is there are better way? Thanks.

Comment: you could squeeze out the dots, then swap the comma for the dot and parse as float. That's only 2 replaces. That's not -terrible- unless you are doing tens-of-thousands of records at a shot

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Using `str_replace()` to remove the dots is not overkill.

```
$string_number = '1.512.523,55';
// NOTE: You don't really have to use floatval() here, it's just to prove that it's a legitimate float value.
$number = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $string_number)));

// At this point, $number is a "natural" float.
print $number;
```

This is almost certainly the least CPU-intensive way you can do this, and odds are that even if you use some fancy function to do it, that this is what it does under the hood.

Comment: or just `$number = str_replace( [',','.'], ['.'], $string_number )*1.0;`

Comment: @Jeff it's right trying to write the less lines of code as possible but I think code readability is a must in developing, even more important than writing less.

Comment: @jeff that would not consider the decimal and return 151252355 in the example , 100 times more

Comment: hmm, yeah, I seem to have overlooked the "Replacement order gotcha" which doesn't occur using mysql's `replace`. So the correct line is `$number = str_replace( ['.',','], ['','.'], $string_number )*1.0;`

Comment: @manuman94, I don't think eliminating an unnecessary function call reduces readability.

Comment: @Jeff I do haha but that's my opinion, of course. I appreciate your efforts to help community, it was only my point of view. Greetings!

Comment: @Jeff You can use strtr instead of str_replace if you're worried about the "Replacement order gotcha".

Answer (score 58):

This function is compatible for numbers with dots or commas as decimals

```
function floatvalue($val){
            $val = str_replace(",",".",$val);
            $val = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $val);
            return floatval($val);
}
```

This works for all kind of inputs (American or european style)

```
echo floatvalue('1.325.125,54'); // The output is 1325125.54
echo floatvalue('1,325,125.54'); // The output is 1325125.54
echo floatvalue('59,95');        // The output is 59.95
echo floatvalue('12.000,30');    // The output is 12000.30
echo floatvalue('12,000.30');    // The output is 12000.30
```

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: This should be the best answer, because it not broke an already decimal number.

Comment: Notice that it is not perfect, sending "1,500" will be converted to 1.5 rather than 1500

Comment: This is because the function expects the number to be a decimal (float) number, so any punctuation will be threatened to transform the input to a float

Answer (score 23):

If you're using PHP5.3 or above, you can use [numfmt_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) to do "a reversed number_format". If you're not, you stuck with replacing the occurrances with preg_replace/str_replace.

Comment: You need also PECL intl >= 1.0.0

Comment: "You need also PECL intl >= 1.0.0"

No, it says you either need to have PHP 5.3 > or you need to install it via PECL intl package 1.0.0.  PHP 5.3+ has the support built in.

Comment: You indeed will need to check whether `intl` extension is enabled. It is not builtin, it has to be either explicitly compiled in or installed as separate extension. Not all hosting providers install it with PHP.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [*NumberFormatter* class](http://php.net/class.numberformatter) with its [`parse` method](http://php.net/numberformatter.parse).

Comment: Available in 5.3 or above only, just as a disclaimer. ;-)

Comment: ...and only w/ the `intl` extension compiled.

Answer (score 13):

Might look excessive but will convert any given format no mater the locale:

```
function normalizeDecimal($val, int $precision = 4): string
{
    $input = str_replace(' ', '', $val);
    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $input);
    if (strpos($number, '.')) {
        $groups = explode('.', str_replace(',', '.', $number));
        $lastGroup = array_pop($groups);
        $number = implode('', $groups) . '.' . $lastGroup;
    }
    return bcadd($number, 0, $precision);
}
```

Output:

```
.12           -> 0.1200
123           -> 123.0000
123.91        -> 12345678.9100
123 456 78.91 -> 12345678.9100
123,456,78.91 -> 12345678.9100
123.456.78,91 -> 12345678.9100
123 456 78,91 -> 12345678.9100
```

Comment: Have you tried 1,000? 

Answer (score 8):

Assuming they are in a file or array just do the replace as a batch (i.e. on all at once):

```
$input = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $input);
```

and then process the numbers from there taking full advantage of PHP's loosely typed nature.

Comment: I would also cast the type float like so $v = (float) str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], $v);

Answer (score 1):

from PHP manual:

> str_replace — Replace all occurrences
>   of the search string with the
>   replacement string

I would go down that route, and then convert from string to float - [floatval](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter_var`.

```
$floatNumber = (float) filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Comment: `var_dump((float) filter_var('223,5', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));` results in `float(2235)`

Comment: In case other filters are needed, you can find them here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

For those who want an example of [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/numberformatter.parse) :

```php
    $test='2,345.67';

//  OOP Version
    $numberFormatter=new NumberFormatter('en-AU',NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    $number=$numberFormatter->parse($test);
    print $number;

//  Procedural Version
    $numberFormatter=numfmt_create('en_AU',NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    $number=numfmt_parse($numberFormatter,$test);
    print $number;
```

Of course your locale may very.

Not sure why anyone would opt for the procedural version.

Note that one major difference between `NumberFormat` and the `str_replace` type solutions is that `NumberFormatter` is sensitive to where you put your thousands and decimal characters; using `1,2345.00` won’t work.