# I need php regular expression for numeric value including "-" and ","

Tags: php, regex

In php is_numeric function not allow '-' and ','.

Comment: You will find information about this and much more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: It might have been more helpful if you'd provided examples of what it should accept/parse - hexadecimal? Scientific notation? Is the ',' only used as a 000 seperator?

Answer (score 5):

This one should work:

```
preg_match("#^-?\d+(,\d+)?$#", "-1,2", $match);
```

Matching one or more digits:

```
"#\d+#"
```

Optionally match a comma followed by one or more digits:

```
"#\d+(,\d+)?#
```

Optionally match a "-" sign:

```
"#-?\d+(,\d+)?#"
```

Allow only this and nothing else:

```
"#^-?\d+(,\d+)?$#"
```

Answer (score 2):

`is_numeric()` does allow negative numbers. I think the problem is just with the comma.

```
is_numeric( str_replace( ',', '.', $number ) );
```

See also [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float)

Answer (score 0):

try with this expression

```
^[0-9 ,-]+$
```