# PHP: If number (with comma), convert it to right number format (with point)

Tags: php, regex, number-formatting

I have an array of mixed values:

```
$row = array('Unspecified risk','Yes','8','3','2','13','none','-1,49','-2,51','-1,46','-1,54'); -1,94   -1,55
```

As you can see it contains text and both negative and positive comma-numbers.

I need to convert the numeric values to the right number format and leave the text values as is.

Now I'm looping over the values:

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
    // If $value is numeric, convert it to the 
    // right number format for use with MySQL (decimal(10,2))
    // If not, leave it be.
}
```

Two related questions I've investigated but cannot find a suitable solution.

- [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float)
- [I need php regular expression for numeric value including "-" and ","](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994704/i-need-php-regular-expression-for-numeric-value-including-and?lq=1)

Could anyone provide a practical example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions.

use `str_replace()` as you need to replace the `','` for a `'.'`, and then use `intval()` or `floatval()` functions to get the numeric value. You can also use `strstr()` to look for the `'.'` and decide if using `intval()` or `floatval()`

Example:

```
$row = array('Unspecified risk', 'Yes', '8', '3', '2', '13', 'none', '-1,49', '-2,51', '-1,46', '-1,54');

    function toNumber($target){
        $switched = str_replace(',', '.', $target);
        if(is_numeric($target)){
            return intval($target);
        }elseif(is_numeric($switched)){
            return floatval($switched);
        } else {
            return $target;
        }
    }

    $row = array_map('toNumber', $row);

    var_dump($row);
```

We use str_replace() to replace the dot for the comma, this way it's a international notation float, even if it's on string, this way later on we can check if it's numeric with `is_numeric()` <-- this function is awesome as it detects from a string if it's a number or not, no matter integer or float etc.

We use the is_numeric to check if the value is integer float or text and return the corresponding value using `intval()` or `floatval()` (the value without the replace applied will not return as a valid numeric, only after switching the , and . it will return true as numeric).

We use `$row = array_map('toNumber', $row);` to apply the changes to the array.

Profit xD

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how do I distinguish between text values and number values?

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you for your efforts: it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I am responding so many years later because I dont find any of the provided solutions reliable enough.

This is a more rigid test if a string contains a float with a comma as decimal separator, and if yes, converts it. Also it removes spaces around the number if needed. It does not really test for malformed numbers.

```
if( preg_match('/^\s*[0-9\.]*,\d*\s*$/', $str)) 
    return (float)str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",trim($str)));  
else
    return $str ;
```

If you know a numerical value ALWAYS has a European notation (so 1.234 without a comma should also be coverted to 1234), it should be:

```
if( preg_match('/^\s*[0-9\.]*,?\d*\s*$/', $str)) 
    return (float)str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",trim($str)));  
else
    return $str ;
```

If you want a truly rigid test, no malformed numbers (like starting with a thousands separator), and that uses ONLY three digits between thousands separators (not all countries use three, though, like India!):

```
if( preg_match('/^\s*\d{0,3}((?<=\d)\.\d{3})*,?\d*\s*$/', $str)) 
    return (float)str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",trim($str)));  
else
    return $str ;
```

And lastly if you want to go even more rigid and also do not want numbers to be able to begin or end with a comma ("1.234," or ",17", which in some cases are considered correct) it becomes

```
if( preg_match('/^\s*\d{1,3}((?<=\d)\.\d{3})*(,\d+)*\s*$/', $str)) 
    return (float)str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","",trim($str)));  
else
    return $str ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = array('Unspecified risk','Yes','8','3','2','13','none','-1,49','-2,51','-1,46','-1,54');
    foreach($row as $key => $var) {
        if(strstr($var, ",") && !is_numeric($var)) {
            $var1 = str_replace(",","", $var);
            if(is_numeric($var1)) {
                $decimal = strstr($var, ',', TRUE);
                $digits = str_replace($decimal, "", $var1);
                $finalValue =  $digits * pow(10,$decimal);
                $row[$key] = $finalValue;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($row);
```

NOTE: This will work for php 5.3 or php 5.3+

Comment: checkout floatval() in the php documentation, if you use floatval($var1) after the str_replace() it gets the value directly. You wouldn't need to do the following 4 operations

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_numeric` to test and `number_format` to format:

```php
foreach ($row as &$value) {
    $number = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    if (is_numeric($number)) {
        $value = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
    }
}
unset($value);
```