# getting int value from comma separated number php

Tags: php

How do I turn a thousand-comma separated string representation of an integer into an integer value in PHP?  (is there a general way to do it for other separators too?)

```
e.g. 1,000 -> 1000
```

Edit (Thanks @ghost) Ideally, decimals should be handled, but I could accept a solution that truncates at a decimal point.

Comment: its too broad, how about other test cases? `1,000.456`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325363/608639)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. That question asks about having a comma as the decimal seperator, not the thousands

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If thats simple as it gets you could use `filter_var()`:

```
$number = '1,000';
$number = (int) filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
var_dump($number);
```

Or

```
$number = '1,000.5669';
$number = (float) str_replace(',', '', $number);
var_dump($number);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can strip a specific character using `str_replace`, and cast as an integer using `intval`. A regular expression filter can also be used to determine if the input string is formatted correctly. Here is what that code might look like:

```
<?php

function remove_delimiters_simple($string, $delimiter = ',') {
    // Removes all instances of the specified delimiter and cast as an integer
    // Comma (,) is the default delimiter
    return (int) str_replace($delimiter, '', $string);
}

function remove_delimiters_advanced($string, $delimiter = ',') {
    // Use preg_quote in case our delimiter is '/' for some reason
    // The regular expression should match validly formatted numbers using a delimiter
    // every 3 characters
    $valid_format_expression = sprintf(
        '/^\d{1,3}(%s\d{3})*$/',
        preg_quote($delimiter, '/')
    );

    // If not a validly formatted number, return null
    if (! preg_match($valid_format_expression, $string)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Otherwise, return the simple value
    return remove_delimiters_simple($string, $delimiter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using PHP >= 5.3, you could use [numfmt_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php), like:

```
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'nl_NL', NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32 );
$num = "1,000";
echo numfmt_parse($fmt, $num); //gives 1000
```

**Note::`nl_NL` is the locale you used in formatting number, and it should be the same when using for numfmt_create**

Comment: This will echo `1` and not `1000`

Comment: @VikasArora it completely depends on locale that is used for adding separators, updated my answer with nl_NL as locale