# Laravel 4 and MYSQL coloumn in float and varchar

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have problem with some table in MySQL database and read it with Laravel4. This is how to look like results when put float(6,2) coloumn for price:
[image: float(6,2)]

And this is look like if I put same column into varchar(6):
[image: varchar(6)]

Did someone know what is the problem and how to fix it? I have other table with float(5,2) column and laravel show results correctly. I use only Model::get() to get data from database and Model (model is name of table in both times) is simple:

```
class Model extends Eloquent
{
use SoftDeletingTrait;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $primaryKey = 'idreceive';
protected $table = 'model';
}
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you use an comma `,` to separate the float decimal, but the system wants an dot `.`

Comment: Yea...it is :) I didn't see it in phpmyadmin! thank you VERY much!

Comment: Alright, I'll make an answer of this then...

Comment: Maybe you should use int or bigint and store price * 100.

Comment: Careful:  MySQL ignores the `(5,2)` part of your `FLOAT(5,2)` declaration. It uses IEEE 32-bit floating format. You may get roundoff errors here and there.

Comment: to solve my problem I change mysql folat format instead float(5,2) I put float(5.2) and everything's works correctly so maybe @Olle Jones answer is correct answer.

Comment: @OllieJones Then should you get the credits for the right answer ;-)

Comment: I give him a up vote ;) is this OK?

Comment: It's something ;-) But the thing is that the answer stays open / unaccepted. So it will end up on an unanswered list on SO, which isn't the case...

Comment: Yea, but only answer that I can mark as answer is not help me, and comment from @OllieJones help me and I wait to him put it as answer ;)

Comment: @StojanKukrika, And I can totally agree with you...

Comment: @OllieJones Could you create an answer?

Comment: can I get more vote up for waiting to @OlieJones put answer :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using an comma `,` instead of an dot `.` to separate the float decimal.

So you need to convert your input from this:

`121,51`

To this:

`121.15`

[Here's an SO question on how to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325608/1175881)

*Code from that answer:*

```
$string_number = '1.512.523,55';
// NOTE: You don't really have to use floatval() here, it's just to prove that it's a legitimate float value.
$number = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $string_number)));
```