# Fetch values containing comma in CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv which contains value like this

```
EX-122PD,XXX,Black,5,"8,2",no_picture_95.png
```

Here's my code

```
if(!file_exists('./csv/'))
   mkdir('./csv/');
$fl_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$file= 'csv/'.md5(uniqid(rand())).$_FILES['img']['name'];
$fl="./".$file;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fl);
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
foreach(glob($fl) as $file)
{
   $fileTemp = $file;
   $fp = fopen($fileTemp,'r');
   $datas = array();
   $timestamp = time();
   while (($data = fgetcsv($fp,1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
   {
       $timestamp = intval($timestamp + 10);
       $data = array(
                     'model_title' => trim($data[0]),
                     'model_series' => trim($data[1]),
                     'color' => trim($data[2]),
                     'brand_id' => trim($data[3]),
                     'category_id' => rtrim(ltrim($data[4],'""'),'""'),
                     'model_image' => 'model_images/'.trim($data[5]),
                     'model_timestamp' => $timestamp,
                     );
         $data['msg']=$this->autoload_model->insert_table('td_model',$data,$timestamp);
   }
}
```

But i am getting my data inserted as

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| model_title  |   model_series  |  color  |  brand_id  |   category_id  |   model_image       | model_timestamp  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  EX-122PD    |      XXX        |  Black  |    5       |        8       | model_iamges/1.jpg  |    1423989807    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

In the category field, it should have been 8,2 but i get only 8

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What datatype is the `category_id` field?

Comment: `category_id` is string or float type in database?

Comment: its string.... mulitple category like 2,3,4,67,32 have been added together

Comment: It's a bad idea to use comma-separated lists in databases. Normalize your data.

Comment: Why can't you just use $data[4] ? does $data[4] not give "8,2" ? Then just remove "" If it contains "". Just asking

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($data[4])`?

Comment: You don't need to use `rtrim` and `ltrim`. `fgetcsv` removes the quotes around the field automatically.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the model, it thinks this field is a number, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar, u were right... I checked the db structure and its int.... That's why its not working...

Comment: Is "8,2" supposed to be a decimal value? If so, bear in mind that PHP doesn't see a comma as a decimal, so if you try to get the numeric value of "8,2", PHP will just see "8". If you need it to be decimal 8.2, then you need to convert it to "8.2". See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: it is 8,2 and not 8.2.....