# Convert string with negative value and decimals to proper type

Tags: mysql

What's the "proper" way to convert

```
string(5) "-2,23"
```

To a value that I can insert in a `DECIMAL(5,2)` Mysql column?

I've tried casting to float, floatval, etc ... None of them seem to preserve the decimals.

Is it because of the comma? I could `str_replace` this with a "." if needed but would rather not, I may encounter values like `"-1.200,23"`

Comment: Possible duplicate with [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4325608/692076)

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, the answer there works, as does the one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, the comma is wrong.

you can insert it like this

```
CREATE TABLE `testdec` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testdec` (`id`, `d`)
VALUES
    (1, -2.23);
```

or you change the comma to dot

```
INSERT INTO `testdec` (`id`, `d`)
VALUES
    (2, REPLACE("-2,23",",","."));
```

but do this careful. this only works is there no other dot in the string like "1.000,12".

if you can have dots in your string do this: first remove dots and then change comma to dot

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE("-456.123,23",".","") ,",",".") ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what if there's a dot in the string? I'm getting these values from an XLS sheet I can't control.  I guess that if there's a dot and a comma, I just remove the dot?

Comment: you can do a double replace. first delete all dots and then change comma to dot: SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE("-456.123,23",".","") ,",",".") ;