# Removing comma on currency string PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I use this jquery plugin to manage currency input from [autoNumber](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) .

From the input, I got the string like this : `30,103,437.60`

Now in POST, I have like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID_INVOICE] => 83
        [DESCRIPTION] => REPAIR
        [QUANTITY] => 1
        [PRICE] => 1,523,000.50
    )
 )
```

Please see in `[PRICE]` . In database, I set PRICE FIELD to `DECIMAL(10,2)`. So, I got `1.00` in my database. I think because the comma on POST->PRICE = `1,523,000.50`.

My question is, how can I save this on database with right format ?
I am using PHP.

Comment: No. You shouldn't store this in database, as MySQL does not store numbers like this. You should only format your number when displaying (via `number_format()` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float)

Comment: You should set `PRICE` field to `double` not decimal and try to remove comma from input string. Just only save number without comma into database. When you display that number you can use PHP `number_format()` .

Comment: Simply use `str_replace(",","",$str);`

Answer (score 0):

Your actual number should always be separate from the formatting so that you can show it to different users using the locale appropriate for formatting. Use `number_format`, `money_format` etc. in php and use the appropriate locale to go to and fro from number to formatted number and back. Even if you are using a jQuery plugin for formatting, I don't understand why it has to make its way to the database as is.