# PHP Float Price Wrong Value?

Tags: php

```
$price = $product->fiyat1 / $currency_values[0];
```

im trying to do this values are

```
$product->fiyat1 = 50,75
$currency_values[0] = 1.0000
```

it is turning this value 50.0000 but i need this 50.7500

Comment: first value 50,75 (,) and second value with dot 1.0000 (.)

Comment: You will have to turn your 50,75 into a different number format. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float

Comment: It's `50.75`, not `50,75`.

Comment: no its coming from an xml and it is abolutely 50,75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $product_fiyat1 = '50,75';
  $currency_values[0] = 1.0000;

  $number1 = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $product_fiyat1)));
  $number2 = floatval($currency_values[0]);


  $price = $number1 / $number2;

  echo $price;
?>
```

Comment: While this "works", you should really use native data types everywhere and just convert to string when displaying, and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

From [Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> Floating point numbers (also known as "floats", "doubles", or "real
>   numbers") can be specified using any of the following syntaxes:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $a = 1.234; 
> $b = 1.2e3; 
> $c = 7E-10;
> ?>
> ```