# PHP - change number format

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_luna_inceput'])){
  $ret =[];
  $sch_luna_inceput = $_POST['get_luna_inceput'];
  $sql = "SELECT
            ...";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $ret[] =[$row['JUDET'], floatval($row['TOTAL'])];
  }
  }
}
  echo json_encode($ret) ;
?>
```

My code sql returns values for `$row['TOTAL']` in number format (1523,45). How can I change in format (1.523,45)? I tried this: `$ret[] =[$row['JUDET'], number_format(floatval($row['TOTAL']),2,",",".")]` and not work.Thank you!

Comment: a few answers in here for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float

Comment: show the ACTUAL query. mysql wouldn't return numbers with "euro" formatting unless you explicitly requested it. Mysql doesn't do any 'fancy' formatting on numbers e, g. `12345.6 -> 12,345.6`

Comment: maybe its a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$num = 1523.45;
echo number_format ( $num, 2, ",", "." );
```

executes 1.523,45

in your case it will be

```
$ret[] = [ $row['JUDET'], number_format( $row['TOTAL']), 2, ",", ".") ];
```

Hope it helped

Comment: will not work  op's number is  `1523,45` not  `1523.45`

Comment: Op lied. 1523,45 is not (float) number format. Its string format, because of the ",".

Comment: Op says no where it is a float