# Substr take effect with comma

Tags: php, mysql, number-formatting, substr

I have input "Weight: 123,4 kg".
I want to save the number to the database so I use `substr` like this

```
 $_POST['product_weight'] = 
substr($_POST['product_weight'], 8, 3);
str_replace(',','',$_POST['product_weight']);
```

But the problem now is that the output is always "123.00". It was a mistake from `substr` or data type?

My form

```
<input type="text" class='numbering' name="product_weight" value="<?=(!empty($form['product_weight']))?number_format($form['product_weight'],2):''?>">
```

Output

```
<td><?=(!empty($each->product_weight))?number_format($each->product_weight,2).' gr':'-';?></td>
```

Comment: please paste how you get the 123.00.

Comment: substr() you just get 3 char, not include `,4`

Comment: `preg_match()` would be more flexible, but [`$weight =
 preg_replace('/[^\d,]/', '', 'Weight: 123,4 kg');`](https://3v4l.org/lvpGU) works with the example.

Comment: Technically, so would `$weight = explode(' ', 'Weight: 123,4 kg')[1];`.

Comment: So would adding [`strpos()` to what you have](https://3v4l.org/FCY84), but that's kinda painful looking.

Comment: @JaredFarrish ya thats good, but thats not change my problem. or maybe substr its not the problem :(. btw, i have a form like that. look at my question

Comment: @Jakbar https://eval.in/815450.   `123,4` length is 5 not 3 or 4

Comment: @KrisRoofe already put that to my code, the output 1,234.00. i think the problem in number format https://3v4l.org/GTkLg

Comment: can  you make your question clear, I don't know what the comma in your code indicate for.

Comment: And  what are your expecting output?

Comment: @KrisRoofe So the point, i want the output 123.40 from input "Weight: 123,4 kg"

Comment: chekc my answer below.

Comment: [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325608/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if you comma is for decimal point refer to this [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325363/6521116)

comma as decimal point, [live demo](https://eval.in/815455).

```
<?php
$string = 'Weight: 123,4 kg';
echo number_format(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', substr($string, 8))),2);
```

comma as seperator, [live demo](https://eval.in/815457)

```
<?php
$string = 'Weight: 123,4 kg';
echo number_format(floatval(str_replace(',', '', substr($string, 8))),2);
```

Comment: solved. thank you. i must learn again converting a number with comma to point :)

Answer (score 0):

This code `substr($_POST['product_weight'], 8, 3)` says "return **3** characters starting at index **8** in the $_POST value" - so all you are capturing is the **123**, not the fractional part of the value.

Comment: so i must use 8, 4? i already try, but still get output 123.00. Btw i adding my form into my question

Comment: 8,4 gets you "123," - you need 8,5 to get "123,4"

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Weight: 123,4 kg';
$arr_string = explode(" ", $string);
echo $arr_string['1'];   //Output : 123,4
echo str_replace(",", ".", $arr_string['1']);  //Output : 123.4
```