# fgetcsv interpreting numbers incorrectly

Tags: php, csv, parsing, fgetcsv

I have a problem when I read csv files that contain values like 886468000000, it gets parsed as 8,86468E+11, which is a huge problem for my app, because I need to parse and retain the number in original form.

I google around the documentation and found nothing, I also tried retypging the exponential string representation as float during parsing , but that does not work either, it returns 8, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64 bit PHP and which version of PHP and on Which OS

Comment: It would also be usful to see a sample of the input file and the code you are using to process it

Comment: @RiggsFolly This issue is easily reproduceable with the info that OP gave, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with PHP 7.2.8 x86 and x64 below are my observations.

The reason that `8,86468E+11` is being converted to `8` is because of PHP's type-casting behavior when a comma is used instead of a period as the decimal separator. See below:

```
echo (float) '8,86468E+11'; // 8 wrong

echo (float) 8,86468E+11; // 88646800000000000 still wrong but getting close

echo (float) '8.86468E+11'; // 886468000000 success!

echo (float) 8.86468E+11; // 886468000000 success!
```

The primary issue for you is that your decimal separator is a comma instead of a period so to remedy this you will need to make use of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$my_num_from_csv = '8,86468E+11';

$my_num_from_csv = (float) str_replace( ',', '.', $my_num_from_csv );

echo $my_num_from_csv; //886468000000
```

Comment: Maybe related: [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325363/608639)

Comment: @jww Thanks, I did consider using that post as a dupe reason but it doesn't really address the behavior that OP is experiencing. One could certainly deduce that foreign decimal notation is the culprit but I think the issue at hand warranted a dedicated answer.