# How can I change the decimal seperator from (.) to (,)

Tags: php

I know that this question might have been answered before. but I still haven't been able to solve it.

my data comes from a CSV file where the data looks like this 1,32 BUT i also have some text in the variable `$getdata` half of it is VARCHAR and the other half is DECIMAL.

but when I look at my site the data is like this 1.00

So my question is How can I change the decimal separator.

The data is located in the `$getdata` variable in the bottom part in the code piece

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){

copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");
// Here i split the csv file, from second line. and using the first and fourth lines as the headers.
if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== false) {

    $header1 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

    $csv->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
    $csv->insertPalleTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));

    $delimiting_row = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use 

    $header2 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

    $csv->createCsvTable($latest_filename);
    while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
        $csv->insertCsvTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata));
    }
}
```

}

I haven't uploaded the full code since that would be way to much code. I'm pretty sure the problem is located at the bottom of the code snippet. if you need any information about the code I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: What is `$csv`? Kind of view engine? I guess you want to change not data, but it's representation, so this more likely to be implemented in class of `$csv`

Comment: It's a pdo class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [number format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) with a simple [str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the comma's so the float can be parsed.

```
number_format(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $your_number_here))), '.', '', 2)
```

If you want a separate readable function instead of a one-liner:

```
function convert_decimal($your_number_here, $decimal_places = 2) 
{
    $without_thousands_dots = str_replace('.', '', $your_number_here);
    $replace_comma_for_dot = str_replace(',', '.', $without_thousands_dots);
    $float_number = floatval($replace_comma_for_dot);
    return number_format($float_number, '.', '', $decimal_places)
}
```

You could skip the floatval part if you don't wish to use rounding or use the number as an actual number and just keep it at returning the $replace_comma_for_dot variable.

For reference how to parse the decimal numbers to floats so you can use number format:

[Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float)

Comment: This works. if all your data is numbers. and thanks for your answer. but i forgot to say that half of my data is text. which does so that i personally can't use it. totally my bad.

Comment: You need to parse the data and iterate the fields yourself. You can always check with is_numeric.

Comment: Sry i dont really know how to do that. can you show me how to do that? the variable with data is $getdata Thanks again for your answer

Comment: The answer I gave helps you with the specific question you asked. I encourage you to ask a seperate question where you asked pointed help how to perform an action on numerical fields, without touching the text fields. Also provide some sample data in that new question.

Comment: Okay Thanks alot for your help! ill do as you suggest :) Really a great help!. ill mark this question as answered :)