# Laravel replace comma by dot in array input before validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to replace all commas by dots in multiple array inputs, **before checking if the input is numeric**. I've got 6 inputs named percentage with an index from 1 to 6.

This is how I'd like to merge the modified percentages with the $request variable.

```php
    for ($c = 1; $c <= 6; $c++) {
        if ($request->percentage[$c] != null) {
          $request->merge([
            "percentage.$c" => str_replace(',', '.', $request->percentage[$c])
          ]);
        }
      }
```

This is how I'd like to validate the percentages.

```php
    $this->validate($request, [
        'percentage.1' => 'required|numeric',
        'percentage.2' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'percentage.3' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'percentage.4' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'percentage.5' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'percentage.6' => 'numeric|nullable',
      ]);
```

However, this solution is somehow not working. If I enter for example 20,77 it says that it's not numeric. 
Does anybody know, what the problem is?

Comment: resolved on [Converting a number with comma as decimal point to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float)

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem that I can't merge the new value with the $request.

Comment: ok, what if you force like `str_replace(',', '.', $request->percentage[$c]) * 1.0` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs to be explained a little more. Like what the `$request` data looks like before modifying it. Or what the output `$request` data looks like after modifying it.

I imagine that the two numbers you said (20 and 77) are supposed to be where the `$c` variable is? So you're looping through 1 to 6 and checking for `$request->percentage[$c]` where `$c` is the numbers you've inputted, e.g. 20 or 77... Because your script is stopping after it hits 6, it will never reach 20 or 77.

Comment: 20,77 does not mean 20 and 77. It does mean 20.77. I want to convert the input of "20,77" to "20.77" and then to check it in the validator!